# How to put a UITextView at the bottom of the TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I want to know what is the correct way to put a UITextView at the bottom of the TableViewController, I don't want it to put in a cell because I already know how to do that, and that is not what I am trying to do, I want to put a UITextView at the bottom of the tableViewController

```
    class ExampleTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    let firstView = UITextView()
    first.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      func setUpTextView() {
    firstView.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(firstView)

         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                                 firstView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
                                 firstView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
                                 firstView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)])
}    }
```

Comment: `self.tableView.footerView = firstView`?

Comment: Do you want the text view to scroll with the table view or always be visible at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @rmaddy I want it to be position at the bottom always as the user scrolls down the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
```

with

```
firstView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50)
```

since the view of the tablecontroller is the tableView then any view added will scroll with it so it's better to create

```
class ExampleTableViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
```

a usual vc with tableView && textView with constraints set properly

---

**Edit:** so either implement `scrollViewDidScroll` and change the bottom constraint as the table with it's `tableView.contentOffset.y`

**OR**

set the view as a footer like

```
self.tableView.footerView = firstView
```

Comment: I want it  to work with a UITableViewController, can you do one with UItableViewController please?

Comment: tried the tableView.footerView = firstView and it does not work for me

Comment: set a height to the view if not works implement https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614972-footerview and  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614967-tableview